# JSTL functions is not found in JSF

Tags: jsf, jstl

I am trying to add an active class on the page the user is currently viewing but I can't manage to use the JSTL functions. What am I doing wrong?

```
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jstl/functions"
```

Using this in a `h:link`

```
styleClass="#{fn:containsIgnoreCase(request.requestURI,'index') ? 'active' : ''}"
```

causes this error:

```
styleClass="#{fn:containsIgnoreCase(request.requestURI,'index')}" Function 'fn:containsIgnoreCase' not found
```

Comment: What about `${fn:containsIgnoreCase(request.requestURI,'index') ? ... }`?

Comment: And `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've got wrong import, it should be :

```
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
```

You forgot about **/jsp**